# Copy column data from one text file add to end of another

Tags: unix, text, multiple-columns

I am looking for a unix cmd or script to extract a column from file1:

```
150807
0
9
5
```

And append to file2:

```
DATE    150706  150713  150720  150727  *150807*
P1AW01  0       0       0       0       *0*
P1AW02  0       12      12      12      *9*
P1CP01  0       0       0       0       *5*
```

The added column needs to left justified and aligned like the others in file2. 
Originally the join command was used, but this removes all the formatting and spacing that was added to file2. Also I'm using an older ver. of korn shell and cannot use the column tool or sed -i option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `paste` command

```
paste file2 file1 > outputfile
```

Comment: Extra information:
If you want to have a delimiter, say "|", you can use this one: `paste -d"|" file2 file1 > outputfile`